# Windows 8 metro apps offline download

Tags: windows-8, download, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Is their any sites available to download windows 8 metro apps for offline installation. Alternative to windows store.Because i don't have internet connection in home.

Please tell me any sites ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be connected to install Windows 8 Store apps. [You cannot sideload an app that has been downloaded from the Windows Store.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852635.aspx)

Alternatively, you can get your app directly from the developer without involving the Store, in which case, installation can be offline. Apps that aren't signed by Windows Store can only be installed on sideloading-enabled devices.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can install Windows apps offline, I did it by capturing the URL windows store referring to, it was a file with .appx or .appxbundle extension. However, the URL contained some security information referring to the Windows Store session and user id. It means you cannot multi-part-download it or resume it if disconnected, very disappointing in case of games with 2 Gb or more data. After that, I installed these packages with PowerShell command

```
Add-AppxPackage [Disk:\File Location\File name.appx]
```

without brackets. It installed and worked correctly.

Waiting for a dedicated side-software (Like Cydia or smith.) that does it in one-click.

Answer (score 0):

It is only a few days for Windows app store to be live and unfortunately in your case, NO option to it for now.